# PHP strange shuffle with require_once and array of strings

Tags: php, apache, require-once

I hit a strange problem with PHP and its `require_once` language construct.

I require file called `EN-en.php`. It contains the English language for my website, I wrote it like this:

```
....
$lang['header']['loginbox']['menu'][1] = "contacts" ;
$lang['header']['loginbox']['menu'][2] = "settings" ;
....
```

Then I user this code to include my file in the whole site

```
require_once $langFile ;
```

Very easy I think, `$langFile is = "/var/www/webstite/langs/EN-en.php"`. But here's come the strange part.

When I use

```
echo $lang['header']['loginbox']['menu'][1];
```

It prints something like "Gontacts" ... I can't understand why, and it's not the only case.. Please someone can help me with this issue?.

Comment: And how can i solve it? Why it "transforms" a 'c' into a 'G' ?

Comment: Well an encoding issue would not change c into G. You said it prints something "like" so I assumed you were being general.

Comment: be sure that your two files are encoded the same way

Comment: Nope sorry I mean that is a G

Comment: Yes they are @artragis I've checked it twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably overwriting your own values in the array.

See this simple example:

```
$test = "some text";
$test['menu'] = 'extra';
var_dump($test);
// produces: string(9) "eome text"
// the first character - $test[0] - gets overwritten
```

Comment: @Claudio Ludovico Panetta You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.